Save as Q&A errors under AI search results
Apparently, we have AI search results now, and a "Save as Q&A" button underneath.
I wanted to explore what this button does (hopefully not what I think it does), but currently, all it does is throw errors:

↓


Actually, what does the link goes to? How does this button save as Q&A, and save to where?

@user1176409 That was what I was exploring. It appears to be a form submit button that submits to "/ai-enhanced-search/save-question", submitting a number of hidden form fields containing the search query, AI summary and some key.

The fkey is your access token, and is standard in all <form>s

My own testing seems to suggest that this is slightly less broken with the wizard enabled. This is obviously not an option outside SO, and the feature is still overall broken (and doesn't currently post the genAI answer), but it doesn't immediately error anymore

Closing this one as I've answered the more direct question of "was the test officially announced". But yeah, should've never happened :)

I do think status-completed would be more appropriate than status-bydesign as this was clearly not by design and action has been taken, but the closure is fine
